# Biztalk Error in WCF OracleDBBinding

Tags: biztalk, wcf-binding, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I used the Consume Adapter Service to create the OrcaleDBBinding to access 3 views from DB. When I tried to test the project I am getting error like,

```
The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "XYZ_DEF_WcfSendPort_OracleDBBinding_Multiple_Custom" with URL "oracledb://abcd.def/". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port.
Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.MetadataException: Argument       
<BtsActionMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Operation Name="Select1" Action="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/View/EMPEXPORT/Select" />
<Operation Name="Select2" Action="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/View/JOBEXPORT/Select" />
<Operation Name="Select3" Action="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/View/POSITIONEXPORT/Select" />
</BtsActionMapping> is invalid.

Server stack trace:
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)".
```

In the oracleDBbinding I even changed the following property

```
"enableBizTalkCompatibilityMode" = True
"useAmbientTransaction" = False
```

But getting the same error.Can anybody help me, why am I getting this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was because I changed the operations in the Logical Ports,which was different from Select. When I changed that to Select it worked.